# Istio sidecar injection fails with no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, istio

My goal is to have a simple Istio setup on a Kubernetes cluster. I was able to achieve this using Docker Desktop on my laptop.

As a next step, thought of doing this on a Kubernetes cluster hosted on CentOS VMs in my company's internal data center. I have a simple Kubernetes cluster setup and am able to deploy a few sample services there. I then setup Istio and created a new namespace with ***istio-injection=enabled***. When I try to deploy a service in the new namespace, I get the below error.

```
> Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook
> "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post
> https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s:
> dial tcp 10.109.98.58:443: connect: no route to host
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, or if I am missing any configuration.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Below is the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
istio-system   grafana-6c8f45499-hv4tq                  1/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-citadel-db8578cc4-bsdcj            1/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-egressgateway-f9c7b6669-h9tvh      0/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-galley-786ff7f89b-42snm            1/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway-5654f8bf65-6bg7n    0/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-pilot-c565b478c-j4f8c              0/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   istio-policy-7d5f97776c-n4c96            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5031       10d
istio-system   istio-sidecar-injector-c7ff9dd99-wh9nf   1/1     Running            0          14h
istio-system   istio-telemetry-55dd49cf85-f26hp         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5117       10d
istio-system   istio-tracing-78548677bc-zqz5j           1/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   kiali-fb5f485fb-ll6bz                    1/1     Running            0          10d
istio-system   prometheus-685585888b-rwl2r              1/1     Running            0          10d
kube-system    coredns-5d4dd4b4db-cj927                 1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    coredns-5d4dd4b4db-kwcqf                 1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    etcd-master-node                         1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    kube-apiserver-master-node               1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-master-node      1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    kube-proxy-49qdq                         1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    kube-proxy-h2p7c                         1/1     Running            1          10d
kube-system    kube-proxy-ncwnx                         1/1     Running            1          10d
kube-system    kube-scheduler-master-node               1/1     Running            0          11d
kube-system    weave-net-67r6x                          2/2     Running            0          11d
kube-system    weave-net-kxvbc                          2/2     Running            2          10d
kube-system    weave-net-spv99                          2/2     Running            3          10d
```

The logs of executing `kubectl --v=9 apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.4/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml` are available [here](https://pastebin.com/KD9S7gK5) (It's too huge to be attached to the post).

Thank you.

PS: I used the word *service* loosely earlier.

-Anoop

Comment: All of your istio pods are up and running, specially the istio-sidecar-injector? What is your version of istio and kubernetes? What CNI you use? What is the version of centos? What loadbalancer you use?

Comment: All istio pods, except policy and telemtry, are up and running which are failing to connect to galley with below error. The version of kubernetes is 1.15.9, istio is 1.4.4, OS is CentOS 7 and CNI is weave

`2020-02-20T12:56:39.493311Z     info    grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {istio-galley.istio-system.svc:9901 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istio-galley.istio-system.svc on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 190.168.1.6:58901->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused". Reconnecting...`

Comment: How did you create your cluster?Is it kubeadm? The requests to the api plane work for GET requests but POST requests get error 500 after 30s timeout. I would say it's either problem with weave or loadbalancer, could you please add `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` so I could actually see if the cluster is healthy? Is there a chance you could change weave to another CNI like calico and try to install istio then? Do you have proxy server?

Comment: Can you try `kubectl --v=9 apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.4/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml` and add the output to your post?

Comment: @jt97, the cluster is created with kubeadm. I don't have an option to change weave to another CNI. Have updated the post with output of above two commands you asked for.

Comment: Based on similiar issue on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/20890) I would i say its CNI problem, there is nothing to do with istio itself, something block it and for me it would be some specific bug on 1.15.9 or weave itself. I made reproduction with newest kubernetes version 1.17.3 and weave and everything works fine, so I would recommend to upgrade your cluster, if you can't I would suggest to open issue at github, either [istio](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues) or [weave](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues) so maybe devs could help.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the connection between your api-server and sidecar-injector. I have faced this issue before and it was that the ports were not open on host level. So, you can check node ports if they are open and also if there are any network policy that you need to open to establish the connection. Check sidecar-injector pod logs if it received any request.

Comment: `info    GET https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/mutatingwebhookconfigurations?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Distio-sidecar-injector&limit=500&resourceVersion=0  in 1001 milliseconds`

Comment: `error   k8s.io/client-go@v11.0.1-0.20190409021438-1a26190bd76a+incompatible/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1beta1.MutatingWebhookConfiguration: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/mutatingwebhookconfigurations?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Distio-sidecar-injector&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host`

Comment: does look like sidecar injector receives the request, but errors out with the above