# Failed calling webhook "namespace.sidecar-injector.istio.io"

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have make my deployment work with istio ingressgateway before. I am not aware of any changes made in istio or k8s side.

When I tried to deploy, I see an error in replicaset side that's why it cannot create new pod.

> Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook
> "namespace.sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post
> "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=10s": dial tcp
> 10.104.136.116:443: connect: no route to host

When I try to go inside api-server and ping 10.104.136.116 (istiod service IP) it just hangs.

What I have tried so far:

- Deleted all coredns pods
- Deleted all istiod pods
- Deleted all weave pods
- Reinstalling istio via istioctl x uninstall --purge
- turning all of VMs firewall
- sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  sudo iptables -F
- restarted all of the nodes
- manual istio pod injection

Setup

- k8s version: 1.21.2
- istio: 1.10.3
- HA setup
- CNI: weave
- CRI: containerd

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311316/istio-sidecar-injection-fails-with-no-route-to-host)? Do you have connection between your api-server and sidecar-injector?

Comment: yes, ports are open and still cannot connect.

Comment: How did you check the connection?

Comment: from inside kube-apiserver pod. tried to connect to 10.104.136.116:443 and it can't. but it can connect when I used the IPs of istiod(sidecar-injector) pod.

Comment: I don't have the visibility and control on the VM, lower network level. I am not sure if something have changed, I tested that this is working before. I already made this work by changing my CNI from weave to flannel. k8s version 1.21.3, containerd 1.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was due to firewall. Following this Istio debug [guide](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Troubleshooting-Istio#sidecar-injection), I identified that the `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/https:istiod:https-webhook/proxy/inject -v4` command was timing out while all other cluster internal calls were ok.

The best way to diagnose this is to open **temporarly** your AWS Security Groups involved to `0.0.0.0/0` for port `15017` and then try again.
If the errror won't show again, you know there's need to fix this part.

I am using EKS with Amazon VPC CNI v1.12.2-eksbuild.1

Comment: thanks, got the same issue, but I am using VMs to setup a k8s cluster, can you advise a guide how to open the ports ?

Comment: it pretty much depends upon where the VMs are and the OS. Please elaborate more

Comment: yeah, right is it quite different on RHEL or ubuntu, thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was related to firewall. More info can be found [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/).

The gist of it is that on GKE at least you need to open another port 15017 in addition to 10250 and 443. This is to allow communication from your master node(s) to you VPC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definite answer unto why is this happening. But kube-apiserver cannot access istiod via service IP, wherein it can connect when I used the istiod pod IP.

Since I don't have the control over the VM and lower networking layer and not sure if they have changed something (because it is working before).

I made this work by changing my CNI from weave to flannel

Comment: Well, I am having the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985819/kubernetes-deployments-are-failed-with-istio-sidecar-injection any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, could you please try to go inside kube-api server and then try if you can connect to istiod via service IP and pod IP? if that's the case  we have same issue

Comment: @letthefirefileslive Well, `ping`,`telnet` and `curl` not available inside `api-server`. How did you check the connectivity?