# Kubernetes deployments are failed with istio-sidecar injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

Our K8 cluster was working for more than a year, recently it got some strange behavior and now when we deploy an app using `kubectl apply -f deployment-manifest.yaml`, it doesnt show in `kubectl get pods`. But shows in `kubectl get deployments` with `0/3` state. `kubectl describe deployment app-deployment`

```
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
  Progressing      False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
```

When I check `kube-apiserver` logs

```
I1115 12:55:56.110277       1 trace.go:116] Trace[16922026]: "Call validating webhook" configuration:istiod-istio-system,webhook:validation.istio.io,resource:networking.istio.io/v1alpha3, Resource=gateways,subresource:,operation:CREATE,UID:00c425da-6475-4ed3-bc25-5a81d866baf2 (started: 2021-11-15 12:55:26.109897413 +0000 UTC m=+8229.935658158) (total time: 30.00030708s):
Trace[16922026]: [30.00030708s] [30.00030708s] END
W1115 12:55:56.110327       1 dispatcher.go:128] Failed calling webhook, failing open validation.istio.io: failed calling webhook "validation.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s: dial tcp 10.233.30.109:443: i/o timeout
E1115 12:55:56.110363       1 dispatcher.go:129] failed calling webhook "validation.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=30s: dial tcp 10.233.30.109:443: i/o timeout
I1115 12:55:56.121271       1 trace.go:116] Trace[576910507]: "Create" url:/apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/istio-system/gateways,user-agent:pilot-discovery/v0.0.0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/$Format,client:192.168.1.16 (started: 2021-11-15 12:55:26.108861126 +0000 UTC m=+8229.934621868) (total time: 30.012357263s):
```

Kube-controller logs

```
I1116 07:55:06.218995       1 event.go:278] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"default", Name:"ops-executor-app-6647b7cbdb", UID:"0ef5fefd-88d7-480f-8a5d-f7e2c8025ae9", APIVersion:"apps/v1", ResourceVersion:"122334057", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedCreate' Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
E1116 07:56:12.342407       1 replica_set.go:535] sync "default/app-6769f4cb97" failed with Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

When I check `kubectl get pods -n istio-system`

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
istio-egressgateway-794d6f956b-8p5vz    0/1     Running   5          401d
istio-ingressgateway-784f857457-2fz4v   0/1     Running   5          401d
istiod-67c86464b4-vjp4j                 1/1     Running   5          401d
```

egress and ingress gateway logs have

```
2021-11-15T16:55:31.419880Z error   citadelclient   Failed to create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host"
2021-11-15T16:55:31.419912Z error   cache   resource:default request:37d26b55-df29-465f-9069-9b9a1904e8ab CSR retrial timed out: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host"
2021-11-15T16:55:31.419956Z error   cache   resource:default failed to generate secret for proxy: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host"
2021-11-15T16:55:31.419981Z error   sds resource:default Close connection. Failed to get secret for proxy "router~10.233.70.87~istio-egressgateway-794d6f956b-8p5vz.istio-system~istio-system.svc.cluster.local" from secret cache: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host"
2021-11-15T16:55:31.420070Z info    sds resource:default connection is terminated: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2021-11-15T16:55:31.420336Z warning envoy config    StreamSecrets gRPC config stream closed: 14, connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host"
2021-11-15T16:55:48.020242Z warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
2021-11-15T16:55:48.020479Z warning envoy config    Unable to establish new stream
2021-11-15T16:55:51.025327Z info    sds resource:default new connection
2021-11-15T16:55:51.025597Z info    sds Skipping waiting for gateway secret
```

Tried to get details as described [here](http://2021-11-15T16:55:31.419880Z%09error%09citadelclient%09Failed%20to%20create%20certificate:%20rpc%20error:%20code%20=%20Unavailable%20desc%20=%20connection%20error:%20desc%20=%20%22transport:%20Error%20while%20dialing%20dial%20tcp:%20lookup%20istiod.istio-system.svc%20on%20169.254.25.10:53:%20no%20such%20host%22%202021-11-15T16:55:31.419912Z%09error%09cache%09resource:default%20request:37d26b55-df29-465f-9069-9b9a1904e8ab%20CSR%20retrial%20timed%20out:%20rpc%20error:%20code%20=%20Unavailable%20desc%20=%20connection%20error:%20desc%20=%20%22transport:%20Error%20while%20dialing%20dial%20tcp:%20lookup%20istiod.istio-system.svc%20on%20169.254.25.10:53:%20no%20such%20host%22%202021-11-15T16:55:31.419956Z%09error%09cache%09resource:default%20failed%20to%20generate%20secret%20for%20proxy:%20rpc%20error:%20code%20=%20Unavailable%20desc%20=%20connection%20error:%20desc%20=%20%22transport:%20Error%20while%20dialing%20dial%20tcp:%20lookup%20istiod.istio-system.svc%20on%20169.254.25.10:53:%20no%20such%20host%22%202021-11-15T16:55:31.419981Z%09error%09sds%09resource:default%20Close%20connection.%20Failed%20to%20get%20secret%20for%20proxy%20%22router%7E10.233.70.87%7Eistio-egressgateway-794d6f956b-8p5vz.istio-system%7Eistio-system.svc.cluster.local%22%20from%20secret%20cache:%20rpc%20error:%20code%20=%20Unavailable%20desc%20=%20connection%20error:%20desc%20=%20%22transport:%20Error%20while%20dialing%20dial%20tcp:%20lookup%20istiod.istio-system.svc%20on%20169.254.25.10:53:%20no%20such%20host%22%202021-11-15T16:55:31.420070Z%09info%09sds%09resource:default%20connection%20is%20terminated:%20rpc%20error:%20code%20=%20Canceled%20desc%20=%20context%20canceled%202021-11-15T16:55:31.420336Z%09warning%09envoy%20config%09StreamSecrets%20gRPC%20config%20stream%20closed:%2014,%20connection%20error:%20desc%20=%20%22transport:%20Error%20while%20dialing%20dial%20tcp:%20lookup%20istiod.istio-system.svc%20on%20169.254.25.10:53:%20no%20such%20host%22%202021-11-15T16:55:48.020242Z%09warning%09envoy%20config%09StreamAggregatedResources%20gRPC%20config%20stream%20closed:%2014,%20no%20healthy%20upstream%202021-11-15T16:55:48.020479Z%09warning%09envoy%20config%09Unable%20to%20establish%20new%20stream%202021-11-15T16:55:51.025327Z%09info%09sds%09resource:default%20new%20connection%202021-11-15T16:55:51.025597Z%09info%09sds%09Skipping%20waiting%20for%20gateway%20secret), but it shows no resources. 
Tried deploying application in non-istio injected namespace and it works without any issue.

We have baremetal cluster running Ubuntu-18.04LTS.

```
istioctl version

client version: 1.7.0
control plane version: 1.7.0
data plane version: none
```

Kubernetes `v1.18.8`

As described [here](http://istio-proxy@istio-ingressgateway-784f857457-2fz4v:/$%20curl%20https://istiod.istio-system:443/inject%20-k%20%20curl:%20(6)%20Could%20not%20resolve%20host:%20istiod.istio-system), ran `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/https:istiod:https-webhook/proxy/inject -v4`

```
I1116 17:05:32.703339   28777 helpers.go:216] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server rejected our request for an unknown reason",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "no body found"
      }
    ]
  },
  "code": 400
}]
F1116 17:05:32.703515   28777 helpers.go:115] Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an unknown reason
```

From ingres-gateway

```
istio-proxy@istio-ingressgateway-784f857457-2fz4v:/$ curl https://istiod.istio-system:443/inject -k

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: istiod.istio-system
```

Edit : in master node `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`

```
clusterDNS:
- 169.254.25.10
```

and we can `ping` to this IP from our nodes.

I found this in `coredns` pod logs

```
E1123 08:57:05.386992       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
E1123 08:57:05.387108       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.233.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.233.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: Do you know, you are using deprecated version of istio and Kubernetes? Could you update both to newest versions? Further, you have this message: `istiod.istio-system.svc on 169.254.25.10:53: no such host`. Could you check this host?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Well, we can not update this as its in client's UAT. Yes, there are no such host in the system.

Comment: Some of the errors suggest the potential of trouble with kube-dns in kube-system namespace. Check that out, potentially. restart the deployment.

Comment: @akokskis `coredns` and `dns-autoscler` both are working. No errors there

Comment: Did you check your DNS settings? This error could be connected to problem with DNS. Another idea is expired SSL certificates. Could you check it?  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known).

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak You mean kube-dns? our kubernetes certificates were recently updated.

Comment: How is look like your `/etc/resolv.conf` file look like? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak in which node? k8 master? or kubernetes pods?

Comment: On master node, could you change it to other value and test again? It seems like you have problem with resolve DNS for `istiod.istio-system.svc`. Did you try to connect to this host directly?

Comment: I tried deploying application in non-istio enabled ns.. It also have the connectivity issue.

Comment: What exactly did this error look like? Do you have some logs?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak No deployment issues, only can not connect to the service, even telnet

Comment: Yes I understand, but what error you got when did you try to connect to this service (even telnet)?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak No route to host

Comment: Do you have some logs, where the connection is broken?

Comment: If your issue has been resolved please post the answer so, that community members can take it as a reference.

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu We had to re install k8 again to solve this issue.